# How Does White Balance Works Inside The Camera Itself When Manually Only A Single Pixel Color Selected To Correct Accordingly (White/Gray)

Tags: camera, rgb, camera-calibration, color-theory

I am looking for the math behind how to calculate the gain factors for each channel after capturing an image with wrong white balance factors (basically I want to feed this information back to the camera API).

Not quite sure whether CAT (Chromatic Adaptation Transform) applies here or something else given the fact that a camera has "no concrete idea" about the illuminant in the scene (outdoor, indoor, fluorescent, tungesten...etc.). However, when selecting a gray/white point on the camera screen to calculate white balance it gets it right and that is what I am looking for.

PS: I assume also that the camera is not doing calculation over the entire set of image's pixels but rather only a small region of interest what the user/eyedropper selected.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and there is no way telling what is the internal camera implementation (the manufactures do not reveal the information). I suppose that the color calibration process that finds the color correction matrix (or equivalent) is also used for calibrating the parameters that helps getting the Illuminant CCT when known gray pixel is given. When the CCT is known the color correction may be more accurate (it's going to work only with natural sunlight).

Comment: well yeah you are right. When I do the color calibration process it compensuates as well for the deviation in the illumination (WB) and it gets it right. However, as it is always recommended to do correct white-balance beforehand for better correction I need to implement that. In addition to the fact that a camera API offers a function called `SetWhiteBalanceByFactors(red,green,blue)` I supposed it should be a familiar algorithm.